# Get POST parameters from Request ( AWS API Gateway - Lambda - Node.JS - Claudia.JS )

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, claudiajs

Im developing a Lambda API in my AWS API Gateway. Im trying to retrieve some parameters from a POST call, but the body comes as a text instead of a JSON, or any type of collection.

I was advised to make the calls using a application/json content type, and also advised to use 'lambda proxy integration', but none of those configurations changed the response object.

```
api.post('/login', function(request) {  
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     console.log(request.body)
```

Log return:

```
----------------------------289602992579875509977825
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myformdata"

666666666666
----------------------------289602992579875509977825
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="otherparameter"

6666666666
```

There is any way I can get a collection of the parameters sent by client?

There is any solution for this using only lambda functions?

Some people are saying that is possible to get post parameters like a "query-string" (ex:one=1&two=2..). Im using PostMan for testing, but this is not working.

Thanks.

Claudia JS Reference:
https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia-api-builder/blob/master/docs/request-object.md

Comment: Are you not using any body parser like busboy etc?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was new to PostMan and was using it incorrectly. After I pass the parameters as a raw JSON body, everything worked correctly. But sadly we may stop using lambdas because one of the main point was to use custom authorizers, but AWS Lambda Custom Authorizers don't receive anything from BODY, what is really silly... AWS team should really change that...